# How to check if Play Service is installed with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I know how to check it with GoogleApiAvailability (by GCM). But this function is not supported be FireBase core library.

my dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
```

Comment: It works, but do we have to do checking w/o importing another library?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure, but I don't think so. When I had this problem I added the whole play-services library, which didn't make sense as it is too large, but then I found out that I could just import the Authentication part which I believe would be of minimal code, and won't affect your method count if that's what you're worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late :) but I can suggest to use the following function to check the Google Play Services availability:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```